# Python Flask: library variable in parameters

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask

I want to create rest interface in flask to support opencv image detection. One of parameters needed for opencv matchTemplate method is match method. This is an integer which is defined as variable in opencv like cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED. I'm wondering how to pass this like name 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED' instead of integer. Do you know how to do this? I want to sent post request with, for example, matchingMethod=cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED parameter and then pass it to the cv2.matchTemplate method(https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an entity's name as a string by calling its `__name__` property.

```py
from cv2 import TM_CCOEFF_NORMED

coeff = TM_COEFF_NORMED.__name__

print(coeff) # should return 'TM_CCOEFF_NORMED'
```

You can now pass `coeff`'s value to your frontend app as a string.

Use the built-in `getattr` function to call it when you receive it from your app.

```py
import cv2

cv_coeff = 'TM_CCOEFF_NORMED' # comes from frontend app

match_coeff = getattr(cv2, cv_coeff) # equals TM_CCOEFF_NORMED's integer value

cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, match_coeff)
```